# Div Scrolling Two Scrollbars

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, scrollbar

I'm having issues implementing a scrollable div.
Probably the error occurs, because one of the inner tables (tableleft) is forcing the first scroll.
And the second scroll is started by the outer div.

How can I remove one of the scrolling bars?

Here's a JSFiddle showing the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/uY3CJ/1/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">

        <style> 
            html {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                height: 100%;
                overflow-x:hidden;
                overflow-y:scroll; 
                background: #5ea71d;
                background:-webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 10, 50% 50%, 850, from(#93d81e), to(#2f5c1b), color-stop(.6,#5ea71d));
                background: -moz-radial-gradient(center 45deg, circle farthest-side, #93d81e 0%, #5ea71d 60%, #2f5c1b 100%);
            }
            #scroll {
                height: inherit;
                width: inherit;
                left: inherit;
                margin-left: inherit;
                overflow: auto;
                background-color: white;
                position: absolute;
                padding: 0px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #innerDiv {
                height: inherit;
                left: inherit;
                margin-left: inherit;
                overflow: auto;
                display: inline-block;
                padding-top: 6%;
                padding-left: 6%;
                padding-right: 6%;
                padding-bottom: 12%; /* provide space for back button */            
                position: absolute;
            }

            table {
                align: left;
                text-align:left; 
                font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;
                font-size: 14px;    
            }

            table td {

                font-weight: regular;
            }

            .table th {
                font-weight:bold;
                text-align:center;
            }

            .tdleft {
                background-color: white;
                box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
                vertical-align: top;

            }
            .tdright {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            .tableleft {

            }

            .tableleft td {
                padding: 4px;
                background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #cccccc) ); 
                background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #cccccc 100% );
            }

            .tableleft th {
                padding: 4px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align:left;
                background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #cccccc) ); 
                background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #cccccc 100% );
            }

            .tableright {

            }

            .tableright td {
                padding: 4px;
                background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #000000), color-stop(1, #4c4c4c) ); 
                background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #000000 5%, #4c4c4c 100% );
            }

            .tableright th {
                padding: 4px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align:left;
                background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #000000), color-stop(1, #4c4c4c) ); 
                background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #000000 5%, #4c4c4c 100% );
            }

            #endimg {
                height: inherit;
                width: inherit;
                left: inherit;
                margin-left: inherit;
                position:absolute;
            }   

        </style>

        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute;">
            <textarea style="border: 2px solid red; position:absolute;" rows="1" cols="8" id="progress"></textarea>
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; width: 1024px; height: 768px; left: 50%; margin-left: -512px;">
        <div style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; width: 1024px; height: 768px; display: block; left: 50%; margin-left: -512px;">

            <div id="scroll">
                <div id='innerDiv'>

                    </br></br>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class='thleft'>Concept and Game Design</th>
                                <th class='thleft'>Technical Implementation</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class='tdleft'>
                                    <table class='tableleft'>
                                        <tr><th>Original Concept</th><td>---------------------------------</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th>Project Leader</th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th>Game Design &amp; Graphics</th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</d></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th>Voice Acting</th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td class='tdright'>
                                    <table class='tableright'>      
                                        <tr><th>Technical Director</th><td>---------------------------</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th>Programming</th><td>---</td></tr>
                                        <tr><th></th><td>---</td></tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan='2'></br></td></tr>
                        <tr><th colspan='2'>Graphics (with the exception of those listed below) created with --</th></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan='2'></br></td></tr>
                        <tr><th>This Computer Game uses this picture from </th><td>-----------------------</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>This Computer Game uses this picture from </th><td>---------------------</td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan='2'></br></td></tr>
                        <tr><th colspan='2' style='color: green;'>MUSIC</th></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan='2'></br></td></tr>
                        <tr><th colspan='2'>This Computer Game uses these sounds from -------------</th></tr>
                        <tr><th></th><td>---------</td></tr>
                        <tr><th></th><td>---------</td></tr>
                        <tr><th></th><td>---------</td></tr>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove overflow auto from the inner div. In this way only the outer div will have a scrollbar

```
#innerDiv{ 
    overflow:auto; /*remove this*/
}
```

Comment: Though I played with the overflow attributes, I obviously missed this one. Thanks!!